# How to convert PDT date to yyyymmdd in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

i have a PDT data in the following format

```
Tue Jul 14 02:00:00 PDT 2015
```

I tried to convert it to yyyymmdd format, but always i got NAN results,

how could i do it ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] to show your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have no idea why you have problems. It could be browser or a typo

In any case here is the short version tested in Chrome and IE11

```js
function pad(num) {
  return String("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
function formatDate(date) {
  return date.getFullYear()+pad(date.getMonth()+1)+date.getDate();
}
var date = new Date("Tue Jul 14 02:00:00 PDT 2015");
console.log(formatDate(date));
```

Comment: It works when i pass pure value, but i have the date stored in a variable,
function convertDate(date) {
 var date1 = new Date(date);
 console.log(date1 +" `DATE");
}

it doesn't work when i passed a variable !!!!!

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. My code has the date object in a var called date. You need to create a date object usign `new Date(whateverYourStringIsCalled)` to pass to my formatter e.g. one step before: What is `\`DATE` ?

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake a passed an extra space, that was the problem :(

Answer (score -1):

```js
function convertPDTDate(_date) {
  if (_date != 'undefined' && _date != '') {
    var convertedDate = new Date(_date);
    var _year = convertedDate.getFullYear();
    if (convertedDate.getMonth() < 10) {
      var _month = '0' + parseInt(convertedDate.getMonth() + 1);
    } else {
      var _month = parseInt(convertedDate.getMonth() + 1);
    }
    var _day = convertedDate.getDate();
    return (_year + '-' + _month + '-' + _day);
  }
}

alert(convertPDTDate('Tue Jul 14 02:00:00 PDT 2015'));
```

Comment: You do not pad day and there is no need to parseInt the int returned from getMonth